# how to populate contents of first tab on load using angular bootstrap UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular ui-bootstrap for tabs. I have ng-click ="ShowAccount()" for the first tab Account, I also want the same function  ShowAccount() to be fired on load of the form.
The project is in Asp.net

The html is

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.testData">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title> Tabs</title>
   <link href="css/en/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <link href="css/en/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <link href="css/en/ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="css/en/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="css/en/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/en/icon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="css/en/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="formTabs" runat="server">
  <div>
        <div ng-controller="TabsDataCtrl">
          <hr />
          <tabset align="left">
           <tab heading="Account" ng-click ="ShowAccount()"> Account
                <div id ="divAccount">
                       <table  id="PNRDataGrid" width="100%"></table>
                               <br />
                   </div>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="Policy">Policy content
               <div>
               <table border ="1" style ="background-color :blue">
                 <tr><td> Test</td></tr> 
               </table>

               </div>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="LoB" ng-click ="ShowLob()">LOB content </tab>
            <tab heading="Coverage">Coverage content</tab>
            <tab heading="Detailed Loss">Detailed Loss</tab>
          </tabset>
        </div>

  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>

  <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/LossHistory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The js file has code

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.testData', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.testData').controller('TabsDataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.businessUnits = [];
$scope.lossHistory = [];

$scope.ShowAccount = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    alert('Account');
   ..
   ..


}
```

This works fine when the user clicks on Account tab, but I want the function to be fired on load 
   say something like:
    $(window).load(function() {} on the (html) aspx page. I dont know how.If I add on the HTML page

```
$(window).load(function() { showAccount();

}
```

It , as expected gives error saying showAccount() not defined. Can some one please help. If there is an event on tab which gets fired on load or something else. Thanks.

When I replace ng-click with select ="ShowAccount" it still does not help. The version of bootstrap.css is v3.0.3 and ui-bootstrap-tpls is 0.11.2.js. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace `ng-click` with `select`.

```
select="ShowAccount()"
```

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZIDazGriXtSt4XRp01I7?p=preview)**